# sending value to server using php and javascript and undefine index

Tags: javascript, php, html

after implementing changes in previous code i did not able to understand the reason that is :                                        Notice: Undefined index: titl on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: ntitle on line 52.
The code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>

#newText
{
overflow:auto;
width:600px;
height:400px;
border:#000000 2px solid;

}
</style>
<script>

     function changeThis(){

     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var formInput = document.getElementById('theInput').value; 
     var title = document.getElementById('title').value; 
     /* formInput will be undefined */
     document.getElementById('newText').innerHTML = formInput;
     document.getElementById('ntitle').innerHTML = title;
     /* also undefined */
//    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
         alert(resp);
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open( "POST", "file2.php", true); //POST Because you use $_POST in php
xmlhttp.send('theInput='+ encodeURIComponent(formInput) + 
         '&newText='+ encodeURIComponent(formInput) +
         '&ntitle='+ encodeURIComponent(title));
    } 
     </script>
     </head>

     <p> <span id='ntitle'></span> </p> 
     <p>You wrote: <span id='newText'></span> </p>
     <body>
     <?php

     $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
     mysql_select_db("project",$con) or die("error db");
      var_dump($_POST);

     $a = $_POST["title"];
     $t = $_POST["ntitle"];
//   echo"$a";
     $q = "INSERT INTO `project`.`event` (`title#`, `title`, `detail`) VALUES (NULL, '$t', '$a');";
     mysql_query($q);

     ?>    
      <textarea id="title" name="title" style="height:20px;">Write Title</textarea><br>
     <textarea id="theInput" name="theInput" style="height:200px;">Write Here</textarea>
     <input type='button' onclick='changeThis()' value='Post event'/>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the difference between `$_POST['theInput']` and `$_POST['newText']`?

Comment: No answer to what? I asked _you_ a question.

Comment: I HAVE not wrote anywhere.

Comment: What have you not wrote where and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the parameters in the `send` method, and use POST:

```
xmlhttp.open( "POST", "file2.php", true); //POST Because you use $_POST in php
xmlhttp.send('theInput='+ encodeURIComponent(formInput) + 
         '&newText='+ encodeURIComponent(formInput) +
         '&ntitle='+ encodeURIComponent(title));
```

**EDIT** Before `xmlhttp.open`, put this to process the ajax response:

```
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
         //alert(resp);
      }
   }
```

Cheers

Comment: thanks but my code is not enering in <?php ........?> any idea. my database name in server is: "project". table name : "event" and column names and there types are: title# (int),title(text), and detail(text). any idea??

Comment: I edited the answer, uncomment the alert and in php do this: `var_dump($_POST)` to check if the variables are arriving fine

Comment: thnx. but my values are not going in server. shell i create another .php file for insert ?? my file2.php is for printing purpose.

Comment: yes i checked values are nt enetring in if(isset....){  } and when i removed this check it give me:                                 Notice: Undefined index: newText in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\p\event.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined index: ntitle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\p\event.php on line 52

Comment: edgar can u tell me wht shd i do for defining index? is it wrong index id="theInput" and other one??

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending your variables in the AJAX call.

```
xmlhttp.open( "POST", "file2.php", true); // Use POST, not GET
xmlhttp.send('theInput=' + encodeURIComponent(formInput) + 
             '&newText=' + encodeURIComponent(formInput) +
             '&ntitle=' + encodeURIComponent(title));
```

Comment: OMG practically the same xD

Comment: thanks but my values are not enering in <?php ........?> any idea. my database name in server is: "project". table name : "event" and column names and there types are: title# (int),title(text), and detail(text). any idea??